# Is it possible to define global variables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, global-variables, postgresql-9.4

I am using postgresql 9.4 and while writing functions I want to use self-defined error_codes (int). However **I may want to change the exact numeric values later**.
For instance
-1 means USER_NOT_FOUND.
-2 means USER_DOES_NOT_HAVE_PERMISSION.

I can define these in a table codes_table(code_name::text, code_value::integer) and use them in functions as follows

```
(SELECT codes_table.code_value FROM codes_table WHERE codes_table.code_name = 'USER_NOT_FOUND')
```

Is there another way for this. Maybe global variables?

Comment: Just stick to the table. Wrap it up in a simple SQL function if you must. Really, though, I see little point in changing the values, why not just make them static?

Comment: @CraigRinger We are developing a new system and a format will be set for the error codes. For instance, [-9 -1] is for permission related errors, [-19, -10] for check constraint errors. However that format is not set for now. And maybe once it is set, later it will be reset. So I want to be ready.

Comment: those aren't error codes,  you return error codes with `RAISE EXCEPTION` and reasonably recent versions up allow you to specify the code that you raise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Building on [@klin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31316737/1104979), there are a couple of ways to persist a configuration parameter beyond the current session. Note that these require superuser privieges.

To set a value for all connections to a particular database:

```
ALTER DATABASE db SET abc.xyz = 1;
```

You can also set a server-wide value using the [`ALTER SYSTEM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altersystem.html) command, added in 9.4. It only seems to work for user-defined parameters if they have already been `SET` in your current session. Note also that this requires a configuration reload to take effect.

```
SET abc.xyz = 1;
ALTER SYSTEM SET abc.xyz = 1;
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Pre-9.4, you can accomplish the same thing by adding the parameter to your server's `postgresql.conf` file. In 9.1 and earlier, you also need to register a [custom variable class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/runtime-config-custom.html).

Comment: I can see the value with SHOW abc.xyz. However I couldn't use it in a SELECT. How can I use its value?

Comment: Use the function from my answer (of course you should change the prefix `glb`).

Comment: is there a limit on size of the config parameters, or a practical limit before it begins to hurt system performance? For example, could it go into say 100mb (on a 100gb server)?

Answer (score 15):

Postgres does not have global variables. 
However you can define custom configuration parameters.
To keep things clear define your own parameters with a given prefix, say `glb`.

This simple function will make it easier to place the parameter in queries:

```
create or replace function glb(code text)
returns integer language sql as $$
    select current_setting('glb.' || code)::integer;
$$;

set glb.user_not_found to -1;
set glb.user_does_not_have_permission to -2;

select glb('user_not_found'), glb('user_does_not_have_permission');
```

User-defined parameters are local in the session, therefore the parameters should be defined at the beginning of each session.

Comment: This configuration parameters could do the job. However is there a way to make them permanent (until I change them)?

Comment: @Nuri: See [`ALTER SYSTEM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altersystem.html), new in 9.4

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION globals.maxCities()
  RETURNS integer AS
  $$SELECT 100 $$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

.. and directly use globals.maxCities() in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trick and declare your variables as a 1-row CTE, which you then CROSS JOIN to the rest. See example:

```
WITH
variables AS (
    SELECT 'value1'::TEXT AS var1, 10::INT AS var2
)
SELECT t.*, v.*
FROM
    my_table AS t
    CROSS JOIN variables AS v
WHERE t.random_int_column = var2;
```

Comment: you can simplify the `variables` CTE to `with variables (var1, var2, trip_type_var as (values ('value1', 'value2', 'one')) ...`

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql does not support global variables on the DB level. Why not add it:

```
CREATE TABLE global_variables (
  key text not null PRIMARY KEY
  value text
);

INSERT INTO global_variables (key, value) VALUES ('error_code_for_spaceship_engine', '404');
```

If different types may be the values, consider JSON to be the type for `value`, but then deserialization code is required for each type.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you work with database-level settings, as in @nick-barnes his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31318830/2780055), these will be set as session *defaults* when the user connects to that database, but *can* be overridden for that session (or a transaction).

If you wish to enforce a database setting, you can do so by going directly to the [`pg_db_role_setting`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-db-role-setting.html) system catalog, as done by this function from my [`pg_safer_settings`](https://github.com/bigsmoke/pg_safer_settings#procedure-test__pg_db_setting) extension (copied here with my explicit permission ):

```sql
create function pg_db_setting(pg_setting_name$ text, pg_role$ regrole = 0)
    returns text
    stable
--    security definer
    return (
        select
            regexp_replace(expanded_settings.raw_setting, E'^[^=]+=', '')
        from
            pg_catalog.pg_db_role_setting
        inner join
            pg_catalog.pg_database
            on pg_database.oid = pg_db_role_setting.setdatabase
        cross join lateral
            unnest(pg_db_role_setting.setconfig) as expanded_settings(raw_setting)
        where
            pg_database.datname = current_database()
            and pg_db_role_setting.setrole = coalesce(
                pg_role$,
                0  -- 0 means “not role-specific”
            )
            and expanded_settings.raw_setting like pg_setting_name$ || '=%'
        limit 1
    );
```

Here's an example to illustrate the difference between the semantics of the `pg_catalog.current_setting()` function and my `pg_db_role_setting()` function:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
CONNECT TO mydb
CREATE ROLE myrole;
ALTER DATABASE mydb
    SET app.settings.bla = 1::text;
ALTER ROLE myrole
    IN DATABASE mydb
    SET app.settings.bla = 2::text;
SET ROLE myrole;
SET app.settings.bla TO 3::text;
SELECT current_setting('app.settings.bla', true);  -- '3'
SELECT pg_db_role_setting('app.settings.bla');  -- '1'
SELECT pg_db_role_setting('app.settings.bla', current_user);  -- '2'
```

Another common pattern is to store settings as `IMMUTABLE` functions or in a table. If you store them in a table, do me a favor and store them as *columns*, not rows. My [`pg_safer_settings`](https://github.com/bigsmoke/pg_safer_settings#procedure-test__pg_db_setting) extension features a `pg_safer_settings_table` which combines these 2 paradigms, by allowing you to store your settings as columns, and automatically maintaining a `current_<col_name>()` function for each of these columns. (The `current_` prefix is configurable.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why store them as columns as opposed to rows? It seems to me that locking is a lot less likely when stored in separate rows than when storing it all in the same row. Love to hear your reasoning.

Comment: Good question, @ThomasHeijtink. The choice for columns is motivated by wanting to have as strong as possible typing and constraints. I don't personally have any use cases involving frequent, parallel setting changes, which is why I don't worry about locking and only worry about data integrity.

I love being able to add a setting like `default_billing_interval` and have it being an actual `interval`.

I could have gone for rows and add a `setting_regtype` column. But, then I feel a bit like I'm reimplementing SQL semantics on top of DB semantics.

Comment: @ThomasHeijtink, If you make an extension that stores the settings in rows instead of columns, I would totally link to it from the `README.md` of `pg_safer_settings`.

Comment: Prompted by you, @ThomasHeijtink, I've documented this design choice in the `README.md` now: https://github.com/bigsmoke/pg_safer_settings#table-pg_safer_settings_table

Comment: thank you for clarifying. Yeah that does make sense. Different needs require different approaches. Thanks for explaining. 