# postgresql user define variabe for sql query

Tags: postgresql, psql

I set the variable in psql like this
`abc=# \set test 'select * from tableName;'` 
I am using ubuntu operating system in which postgresql installed
When I exit the terminal it becomes lost So for permanent purpose what should I do?

Comment: If you need to store data in the database, I would highly recommend a table.

Comment: No I just create the shortcut for long queries so I set the variables, but when I quit to psql it lost and again I need to set the variable, For permanent purpose what should I do so not need to set the variable again and again

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create a configuration table to store all your parameters.

But, if you are looking to use OS level variables, this is how you could pass Shell variables in `psql`

```
[pguser@test ~]$ export test_var="select 'Hello';"
[pguser@test ~]$ psql -A -t -q -d YOURDB -U youruser -p 5432 <<INP
${test_var}
INP
Hello
```

`-A -t -q` options are just to suppress column headers and error output.

To set your variable  **permanently**, put this line in `~/.bashrc , ~/.bash_profile` or any appropriate initialisation file for your shell.

```
export test='select * from tableName;'
```

If you want to define global variables in pg environment, you may refer this: [Is it possible to define global variables in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316053/is-it-possible-to-define-global-variables-in-postgresql)