# Postgresql & PgAdmin SIMPLE variable

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I don't understand why creating variables has to be so complicated in pgAdmin but can someone please help me with this concept. I would like to just create a basic variable that is a `Name` from a record. And then I want to search for that `Name` again. So here is a basic example of what I need:

```
VAR1 = SELECT "Name" 
FROM "Client"
WHERE "ID" = '1'; // This select will return 'Peter'

SELECT * FROM "Client" WHERE "Name" = VAR1;
```

I have tried all of these. Creating a temp table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE VAR1 AS VALUES (SELECT "Name" FROM "Client" WHERE "UUID" = 1;);
SELECT * FROM "Client" WHERE  Name = VAR1.column1;
...
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: CREATE TEMP TABLE VAR1 AS VALUES (SELECT "Name" FROM "Client...
                                          ^
```

This doesn't work in pgAdmin, it only works in `psql`:

```
\set VAR1 (SELECT "Name" FROM "Client" WHERE "ID" = '1')
SELECT * FROM "Client" WHERE name = :VAR1;
```

This doesn't work either:

```
set session my.vars.id = SELECT "Name" FROM "Client" WHERE "ID" = 1;
SELECT * FROM "Client" WHERE "Name" = current_setting('my.vars.id');
...
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: set session my.vars.id = SELECT "Name" FROM "Client" WHERE "...
                                 ^
```

This is not working at the moment, but it is ridiculous to expect me to write all this code for a simple `VAR1 = x`. Even if you get this working, I please don't want this as an answer:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  VAR1 text = (SELECT "Name" FROM "Client" WHERE "UUID" = 1);
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT * FROM "Client" WHERE "Name" = VAR1);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
...
ERROR:  RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning void
LINE 6:   RETURN (SELECT * FROM "Client" WHERE "Name" = VAR1);
                 ^
```

Using `WITH` doesn't work because the you can only use the variable once right below the `WITH` block. I want to be able to use the variable throughout the whole script.

**Why does this have to be so complicated? VAR1 = x**

I have read many other answers (that is where I got all of my test). So please don't reference them unless they offer something different.

Comment: "*Why does this have to be so complicated*" - because SQL (the query language) has no concept of variables.

Comment: See [Is it possible to define global variables in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31316053/1995738)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You marked my question is a duplicate of the other one where the `WITH` solution is the marked answer. I specifically said that the `WITH` solution doesn't work, because you can only use the `WITH` variable on query later...thanks for the explanation though

Comment: See my answer to the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29469454

Comment: You can also use a different SQL client that provides variables

Comment: I did try your answer (check my question's code), can you show me how to fix it then? I am getting an error